# Deriving stochastic integral $ X+\frac{1}{2}\int_t^T Z_s^2 ds - \int_t^TZ_s dB_s$

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals

> If $X,\eta<\infty$ where 
>   $$  \exp(X) = \mathbb{E}[\exp(X)]+ \int_0^T \eta_s dB_s$$
>   Then let $$ \exp(Y_t) = \mathbb{E}[\exp(X)|\mathcal{F}_t]$$
>   Prove that for some $t\in [0,T]$, that there is a stochastic process $Z$ where the following holds true:
>   $$ Y_t = X+\frac{1}{2}\int_t^T Z_s^2 ds - \int_t^TZ_s dB_s$$

I know that $Y_t = \ln\bigl(\mathbb{E}[\exp(X)|\mathcal{F}_t]\bigr)$ . Then we define an Ito process $S_t = S_0 + \int_0^t \eta_s dB_s,$ such that $S_0 = \mathbb E[e^X]$, then $S_t = \mathbb E[\exp(X)|\mathcal{F}_t] >0,$ so $ln(S_t) = ln(\mathbb E[\exp(X)|\mathcal{F}_t])$, applying Ito's Lemma to this then gives 
$$ ln(S_t) = ln(S_0) + \int_0^t f'(ln(S_s)) dX_s + \frac{1}{2} \int_0^t f''(ln(S_s)) d\langle ln(S)\rangle_s $$

I couldn't get the end answer from here though..

Comment: By the way your Itô's formula application is a bit fishy, first write $dS_t= \eta_s dB_s$, then $dY_t=d(ln S_t) = \frac{\partial ln S_t}{\partial x} dS_t + \frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial^2 ln S_t}{\partial x^2} <dS_t>= \frac{1}{S_t} \eta_s dB_t  -\frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{S_t^2}\eta_s^2ds$ finally as $S_t=exp(Y_t)$ and posing $Z_s=  \frac{\eta_s}{S_t}$ and finally integrating yield the expression in my post.

Comment: By the way where does this exercise come form ? Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So from Itô (on $S_t$ and $ln$ to get $Y_t$'s SDE), you get the following :
$$Y_t=Y_0 -\frac{1}{2} \int_0^t Z_s^2 ds + \int_0^t Z_sdB_s$$ with   $Z_s= \frac{\eta_s}{e^{Y_s}}$.
Now observe the following :
$$exp (Y_T)=exp (X)$$ so $$X=Y_T=Y_0 -\frac{1}{2} \int_0^T Z_s^2 ds + \int_0^T Z_sdB_s$$ (and by the way you can see that taking $t=0$, that $Y_0= ln (\mathbb E[exp(X)])$ but we won't need that).

We are almost done now take $Y_t +(X-X)$ and the following comes :
$$Y_t=Y_t +(X-X)=X - (\frac{1}{2}\int_0^t Z_s^2 ds - \frac{1}{2}\int_0^T Z_s^2 ds) +(\int_0^t Z_sdB_s-\int_0^T Z_sdB_s)$$    or
$$Y_t= X + \frac{1}{2}\int_0^T Z_s^2 ds -\int_t^T Z_sdB_s$$

So I think there is typo in your exercise as I have found a minus term on the anticipative term of Brownian integral in the final representation of $Y$ unless mistaken.